# How to allow clicking on <a> with z-index of -1

Tags: html, css, z-index

I'm trying to allow a user to click on a link that has a z-index of -1. I want the rest of the content of the page to go over the link when scrolling down, which works perfectly, but I can't click on the link.

HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id = "aWrap">
    <a href = "#foo">I should be able to click this</a>
    </div>
    <div id = "foo">
      <p>Rest of page content</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#aWrap {
  height: 100vh;
}

a {
  display: block;
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#foo {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 40vh;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Here's my pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XKNRXx?editors=1100

Comment: Any particular reason why you're setting anchor's `zIndex` to `-1` in the first place? If the content actually overlays it, there's no way the user would be able to see the link.

Comment: if you remove z-index, you should be able to click on it when you scroll down.

Comment: @choz The content would only overlay the anchor after the user scrolls down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an updated codepen working as you're expecting:

http://codepen.io/thecox/pen/xORdEe?editors=1100

When you use a `z-index` of -1, the element is placed below all elements, including its parent element. Updating to `z-index: 0` and `position: relative` / `z-index: 1` on the overlapping container corrects this. Only elements which are positioned work with the `z-index` property.

Answer (score 1):

Add `z-index:0` to `a` tag and add relative position to next div with `z-index:1` like this:

```
  a {
      display: block;
      z-index: 0;
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }

    #foo {
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      padding: 40vh;
      text-align: center;
      position:relative;
      z-index:1
    }
```